Usage of python (under virtual environment) in a qsub script
I prepared two virtual environments:
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m venv venv1
/usr/bin/python3 -m venv venv2

I want to submit a job with "qsub -N test test.sh"
In test.sh I want to use python
test.sh:
#! /bin/bash
#PBS -q long_time
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=128:mpiprocs=128

#Activate your virtual environment
#source /path-to/venv1/bin/activate
source /path-to/venv2/bin/activate

# Change to the directory from which the job is submitted (if needed)
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
# Run your Python script
python a.py

If I activate venv1, I get the error below
/var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/... line 16: python: command not found 

As you can see, python is not found.
On the other hand, when activating venv2
python is found, the program works
I do not undestand why venv1 gives me an error...?
How can I modify the program so that I use venv1's virtual environment?
Add one more infomation
As the 3rd method, I install python from sorce code in
~/software/python/Python-3.9.13/install/bin and lib
If I use this bin so that I make venv
~/software/python/Python-3.9.13/install/bin/python3 -m venv venv3

and
source /path-to/venv3/bin/activate

this also works, python is found
I'm not undestand why the 1st one does not work...
